# How can I clean the topology of this rectangular shape which was beveled?

Tags: modeling, topology, bevel

I was wondering if there are methods of improving the topology to prevent ngons from occurring in the shape pictured below:

[image: Recentangle with bevel curve]

I have attempted to inset the face to continue quads but it ends up like this:

[image: Inset faces]

When attempting to add more loop cuts and auto smooth, the ngon has artefacts. Attempting to sculpt doesn't allow any work done to the object.

[image: ngons cause issues and sculpting doesn't work]

I appreciate your help.

Comment: hello, you don't necessarily need to avoid ngons if the ngon doesn't cause any problem

Comment: @moonboots thank you for your reply. Unfortunately I'm having issues when trying to sculpt. Also when adding more loop cuts and auto smoothing it causes strange artefacts, I have updated the post with a picture attached.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sculpt, keep a low-poly version, then you could create this topology for example:

[image]

Then subdivide with a *Subdivision Surface* modifier in order to get enough topology

[image]

Comment: Thank you for showing me this, to achieve the desired result in the first image was this just a matter of a simple Subdivision Surface modifier applied?  Or was this a remesh?

Comment: i've used J to join and alos the knife (K to activate, A to cut orthogonally), and for the horizontal edge loops on bottom part I've loop cut (Ctrl R)